# ANDing with different bit lengths

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I have the following:

```
void calculate(unsigned long num1, unsigned long num2){
   int32_t invertednum2 = ~(num2);    // yields 4294967040
   printf("%d\n", invertednum2);      // yields 255

   // num1 is 3232236032
   int32_t combine = (int32_t) num1 & num2;
   printf("%d\n", combine);           // yields 0???
}
```

I'm trying to AND num1 and num2 so that the result would be:

```
   000000000000000011111111
```

I'm not sure if I'm ANDing correctly with two different bit lengths or if I should cast.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: 1. Use `unsigned` integer types. 2. You say what result you want, but you don't say what your inputs are. (Well, we can deduce what `num2` is, but we have no idea what `num1` might be.) It's also unclear what the intent is.  Perhaps more examples would help.

Comment: Why are you using int32_t instead of uint32_t?

Comment: Perhaps you don't know what AND means. You're getting the right result. (I have no idea why anyone thinks signed vs. unsigned is relevant here ... the results will be the same with uint32_t.)

Comment: num1 and num2 have the same bit length, so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: what is your num1? please provide inputs..que it self in not clear

Comment: @Barmar `(int32_t)num1` is not the same length as `num2`, so the question does make *some* sense.

Comment: I think he intended `(int32_t) (num1 & num2)`

Comment: I've added what num1 is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't AND different bit lengths in C, because you can't apply any binary operator (except shift) on operands of different types.  If you write code where the operands are different types, the C compiler will first convert them to the same type (and so the same size) BEFORE doing the operations.  There are 7 pages in the C spec (section 6.3) devoted to the details of precisely how this happens.

As a result when you have:

```
int32_t combine = (int32_t) num1 & num2;
```

and `num1` and `num2` are both `unsigned long` and that is 64 bits, what will happen is:

1. The cast will truncate `num1` to 32 bits
2. The AND has different operand types (int32_t and uint64_t), so the int32_t will be sign extended to 64 bits.
3. The AND is performed on those two 64 bit values
4. The result is truncated back to 32 bits and stored in `combine`

Now since `num1` is 3232236032 (0xc0a80200), steps 1 and 2 will convert that to 0xffffffffc0a80200, which will be ANDed with num2, and then those top 32 bits will be thrown away.

In contrast, if you had:

```
int32_t combine = (int32_t)(num1 & num2);
```

It would do a 64 bit AND on `num1` and `num2`, and then trunctate to 32 bits to store in `combine`.  While this is quite different from the first case, the resulting value stored in `combine` will be exactly the same -- only the intermediate value (the result of the bitwise AND) that noone ever sees will be different.  As a result, the compiler is free to rearrange things and generate the exact same code for these two cases.

Answer (score 0):

First, you didn't say what `num1` is, so we have no idea what the result should be. Second, 4294967040 is too large for `int32_t`. Since your arguments are `unsigned long`, your other variables should be as well ... but then use `%lu` instead of `%d`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added what num1 is. I've tried unsigned long.